# storing image path in xml

Tags: php, xml, image, path

Hii,
Have created a form which on submitting generates an xml dynamically and thereby an HTML is generated from the details submitted in the form.

All the textbox inputs work fine and data is successfully displayed in the html.However,theres an option for the user to even upload images.The image upload works fine too and the image gets stored successfully in the respective folder too.

However,i dont know why but i just cant retrieve the image for display.Tried print_r($_FILES); just to verify,result is shown correctly here.However,when i checked the xml file,i noticed that the node of the image is always empty even after uploading.

So basically,inspite of the image getting uploaded to the server,yet the path of the image is not getting stored in the xml node,thats why it still cant be retrieved.

Can anyone pls help me?
I have uploaded the code snippet of the php file at : http://codeviewer.org/view/code:16df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$sXml.="<image><![CDATA[".$_POST['img'.$i]."]]></image>";`

Did you mean to use the POST variable for the image path?

Comment: Changed it to $_FILES yet no luck :(

Comment: oh my god...no i never tried that.I just replaced $_POST with $_FILES without changing the other parameters!So silly of me... Anyways thanks so much.Tried what you said,and it did work :)Thanks a ton!